# Setting Connection String throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: vb.net

I've effectively copied the first step I would use to connect to our DB from a `C#` project into `VB.NET` but `VB 2010 Express` is getting upset.

I have a winForms with an empty DataGridView. Behind this form I have added the following code:

[image]

In the `App.config` file I have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name ="WH" connectionString="USER ID=xxx;PASSWORD=xxx;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=WH" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

At this point I thought I'd debug and I'm already getting an error:

[image]

What is the likely cause of this bug?

Comment: Are you sure that the exception is on the connectionstring read?

Comment: I'm with Steve. Copied the code you've shown into a new project and it worked fine. Is there anything else on the form that could be throwing the exception?

Comment: @Steve I'm pretty inexperienced using `VS` and `.NET` : how can i check if the exception is on the connection string read?

Comment: @MrBlue - Just set the form up - all it has is an empty DataGridView - I'll try creating a brand new form and copy the code in

Comment: hmmm - just created a blank form, with _no_ controls, and added the code with the addiiotnal reference to `system.configuration` and getting the same error.

Comment: Well I can replicate the error by changing the name of the connection string being referenced to something that doesn't exist. Try something like `For Each connectionString In ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(connectionString.name)` `Next` to check the name you're using exists.

Comment: Check that the App.config file is the same in your App's folder. Once I got the same error because my app was reading other App.config.

Comment: @MrBlue ok - if I step into the program and then type `?ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(0).Name` in the immediate window it returns `"LocalSqlServer"`. If I then type `?ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("WH").Name` in the Immediate window it returns `Referenced object has a value of 'Nothing'.`

Comment: hmm; new projects seem to be connecting ok now; I've changed nothing; I can't replicate the error either;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative, you could try creating a new settings file rather than using the `ConfigurationManager` class.

Say you create a file called ConnectionStrings.settings with a setting named WH, you can access the value via `ConnectionStrings.Default.WH`.

Comment: I'm wondering if my VB Express application isn't somehow hard wired to  `"LocalSqlServer"`....VB Express and SQL-Server Express are both part of a course I'm doing, whereas in this question I'm trying to link from this VB Express to my work instance of SQL-Server 2012